# parallel processing in q function called from python

Tags: kdb, pyq

From [q reference](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/peach/):

> In order to execute in parallel, q must be started with multiple
>   slaves, using -s in the command line, and the \s system
>   command.

Is it possible to make use of `peach` in a q function which is called from pyq (python)?

```
from pyq import q
q('\l myscript.q')
q('foo[]')         / peach inside
```

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with pyq kernel.

Comment: This question might be better off asked on the official support channel (k4.topicbox.com) since it's now an officially supported product

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make use of peach in a q function which is called from pyq (python)?

Yes, when you start pyq, you can pass q options to the underlying q process after a special -- argument, so you can run pyq with say 4 slaves as follows:

```
pyq -- -s 4
```

> I'm using Jupyter Notebook with pyq kernel

When using pyq kernel, you can specify q arguments in the kernel.json file.  You can find the location of the kernel.json file using the following command:

```
jupyter kernelspec list | grep pyq
```

To specify 4 slaves, append "-s", "4" to the **end** of the "argv" list.